# Display negative Y values above zero instead below in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

I want to make use of a scatterplot to visualize points of interest on a map-like basis.

The coordinates are take from Minecraft and look like this:

```
[10, -10]
```

If I put them straight into a simple scatterplot, everything looks ok except the negative Y values from minecraft, towards north, are displayed in a normal mathematical way, downards.

I don't want to mess with the numbers in a way I have to multiply them by `-1` and taking care of that until EOL.

How can I turn the negative Y values beeinig displayed above zero analog to *north*?

https://jsfiddle.net/vwdce0nt/

Comment: have you tried using `Math.abs(...)` on the values?  like `coordinatesArray.map(Math.abs)`

Comment: @Deryck could you jsfiddle your idea? I have updated the one in my question to represent north and south.

Comment: if you are doing this with simple static data like in the fiddle you have provided here, you can just change the values to not be negative.  if you are getting the data dynamically and passing it to `.series` in the initialization somewhere, you will just need to map over it at that point like `seriesData.map(obj => ({ ...obj, data: obj.data.map(Math.abs) }) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the option `reversed` of the y-axis:

```
 yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Z'
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    min: -1000,
    max: 1000,
    reversed: true,
},
```

See [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.reversed)